# Git number of commits per author on all branches

Tags: git, version-control, commit

I'd like to get the number of commits per author on all branches. I see that

```
git shortlog -s -n
```

Prints a very nice list but it is not counting the commits that are not yet merged from other branches. If iterate this command over every branch then obviously the common commits get counted multiple times. Could you give me a script/command that would yield me the overall picture?

Comment: Any way to include users who did not make commits? Show them as 0?

Comment: The problem is every programmer in the universe excluding the actual committers are potentially users with zero commit in your repo. So the list would be too long.

Answer (score 927, accepted):

```bash
git shortlog --summary --numbered --all --no-merges
```

Will give you statistics for all branches.

**EDIT**: Added `--no-merges` to exclude statistics from merge commits.

Comment: If anyone also need emails then you can use `-e` command like this: `git shortlog -s -n -e --all`

Comment: if you need a time period, specify `--since="22 Aug 2017"`

Comment: @mBardos `--since="22 Aug 2017"  --before="01 Sept 2017"` to get period

Comment: @Kuncevic I meant period as a date from past till now ;)

Comment: Any way to include users who did not make commits? Show them as 0?

Comment: @sloven Anyone not part of that result made 0 commits :)

Comment: Can this be filtered specific to any branch?

Comment: If you get 0 results with --since="22 Aug 2017" you can try with --since="2017-08-22".