# Gem to count the total git commits made by a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Is there a ruby gem to display the total commits made by a user in terminal ? And also to show the output in terms of pie chart on UI ?

Comment: the equivalent git command - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839083/git-number-of-commits-per-author-on-all-branches

Comment: are you talking about continuous integration or just only commit count ??

Comment: Only commit history by a user.

Comment: I need the name of that gem, this is not about command its gem so i dont think the above stackoverflow answer will solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged) gem has a way to do it.

```
require 'rugged'
repo = Rugged::Repository.new('git-project-dir')
walker = Rugged::Walker.new(repo)
walker.sorting(Rugged::SORT_TOPO | Rugged::SORT_REVERSE)
walker.push(repo.head.target)
walker.count { |c| c.author[:email] == "<user_email>" }

=> 52
```

Without using any gem, a shell command from your git repo directory can get you the total number of commits for an user:

```
`git shortlog -s -n --all| grep <user> | cut -f1`
```

Comment: I want to do it using gem, there is a rubygem to count commits and displays the content using pie chart.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it'll be good if you could tell any other gem's name.

Comment: you can achieve the same using Rugged. check my updated answer.