# Github API: How to get the top contributors (sorted) for a given repository?

Tags: github, github-api

I don't see a clean/obvious way to do this using the github api. So I'm not even sure it's really that easy/feasible to do. Am I forced to compute this locally (eg: query for ALL the commits of a given repo, and then tally them by author?)

If there is a clean 1-2 API call step way, instead of iterating over all the commits, that would be great.

It's not a duplicate, because the other question is asking how to do this with command line. I need to only use the github API because I will be going over 200+ repos and it needs to be fully programatic, as it starts from the list repos api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git number of commits per author on all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839083/git-number-of-commits-per-author-on-all-branches)

Comment: Are you looking for this?: `https://api.github.com/repos/scala/scala/contributors`? Found this there: https://github.com/blog/643-contributors

Comment: @XavierGuihot That would probably do it. Just as long as I can use that same api enterprise (after logging in of course).

Answer (score 6):

Based on comment of [Xavier Guihot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48874412/github-api-how-to-get-the-top-contributors-sorted-for-a-given-repository/48879113#comment84752902_48874412), I add parameter for query

```
?q=contributions&order=desc
```

It become to

https://api.github.com/repos/scala/scala/contributors?q=contributions&order=desc

(You can use this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?hl=en , it help you easy to view result)

Comment: This gets only 30 how do i get all ?

Comment: Not sure if there's a specific query paramter, but you can use the `per_page=<num results per page>` query parameter to get the number of required results per page (max. 100), and also the `page=<num. pages>` query parameter to get the number of pages of results. Refer to the API doc for the repos endpoint - https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#list-repository-contributors