# Azure DevOps commits by developer

Tags: azure, azure-devops, commit

In Azure DevOps, is there an easy way to find the total number of commits by developer within a specific time period? Possibly with the number of lines added/removed as well? Based on 1 repo or multiple.

Similar to this image from GitHub...

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could check out the marketplace. A possible extension would be [Contributions Graph](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.contributions), which also allows you to select one or more repositories.

[image: Contributions of a user]

Answer (score 17):

I think this is a general git question.

What we did in our peoject is similar to [Git number of commits per author on all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839083/git-number-of-commits-per-author-on-all-branches)

You would go for something like:

`git shortlog -s -n --all --no-merges --since="22 Aug 2019" --before="01 Sept 2019"`

This would result in:
[image]

you could also add the author by adding `--author=name` like:
[image]

I would suggest to read the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) for options.

Comment: While the information in your answer is good, it doesn’t answer OP’s questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you use VisualStudio, a quick way to achieve the number of commits is to copy and paste the changeset history into excel and filter by user. It's not something I'd want to use regularly but it works.

It's worth mentioning though, that lines of code committed can be misleading and therefore unfair to the coders. Good code can be a lot shorter than bad code. And lots of code might just contain external libraries etc.